# SQL using CASE STATEMENT - compute for sum of amount based on the existence of it in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case, exists

**UPDATED**

I am working on an online sales monitoring system for Shopping mall tenants in different locations, using an existing system which I am only to upgrade and modify. All Sales transactions are to be summed up including the discounts as default, Only to exempt the discount to the total summation of sales when the discount is APPROVED. My question will focus on that transaction - ***getting the right sum of total sales considering the exclusion and inclusion of discount amounts per given date and per tenant.***

Here's the preview of existing database structure for your reference.

[image: Database structure]

**Scenario / Example:**

I would like to get the sales report of Location1 with 2 tenants for the month of January 2014, CMJOLL13 (tenant1) discounts for ***jan 1 and 3*** are approved, CMMISL13 (tenant2) discounts for ***Jan 1 and 2*** are approved.

I should get the total monthly sales report of that location listing the 2 tenants total sales, considering the discounts deductions and inclusions.

```
Daily Table 

   Tenantcode   Date        Other   Cash     Charge     Gift      GrossSales 
                                                                  (Formulated column)

   CMJOLL13     01/01/2014  100     100      100        100       300
   CMJOLL13     01/02/2014  100     100      100        100       400
   CMJOLL13     01/03/2014  100     100      100        100       300
                and so on
   CMMISL13     01/01/2014  100     100      100        100       300
   CMMISL13     01/02/2014  100     100      100        100       300
   CMMISL13     01/03/2014  100     100      100        100       400
                and so on



Discount Table

            Date        Tenantcode

            01/01/2014  CMJOLL13
            01/03/2014  CMJOLL13
            01/01/2014  CMMISL13
            01/02/2014  CMMISL13
```

### Desired / Right Output

```
Monthly Table (Jan 2014) - will display the summation amount based on the example only

     Tenantcode   GrossSales
     CMMISL13     1000
     CMJOLL13     1000
```

---

**Here's the code that I currently have**

```
select a.tenantcode,  convert(varchar(10), a.date, 101) as Date,  
        SUM(a.other)  as Other, SUM(a.CASH) as Cash,
        SUM(a.CHARGE) AS Charge, SUM(a.GIFT) AS Gift,

        case 

        when a.date IN (select  Z.date from discount Z inner join daily a on z.date = a.date and z.tenantcode = a.tenantcode where Z.date between '01/01/2014' and '01/31/2014' and a.location = 1)

        THEN (SUM(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift))

        ELSE (SUM(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift) + SUM(a.other))

        END as GrossSales

        into #MonthlyTemp

        from  TENANT b inner join LOCATION c on b.location=c.location inner join DAILY a on a.tenantcode=b.tenantcode

        where a.location = 1  AND 
            a.date  BETWEEN  '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014'

        GROUP BY a.tenantcode , a.date 




    SELECT tenantcode, SUM(GrossSales)
        from #MonthlyTemp
        where LOCATION = 1   AND
        date  BETWEEN  '01/01/2014' and '01/31/2014'
        group by  tenantcode
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT BASED ON QUERY**

```
         Tenantcode   GrossSales
         CMMISL13     900
         CMJOLL13     900
```

Obviously it does not return the right desired output. ***I think it is because the date in case part is seeing all dates in the discount table***.  I have used temp table in the above code, Now I am thinking of using While loop in sql to test it per location.

Any help will be appreciated. Hoping for your expert advice. Have a great day ahead!

Comment: Shouldn't the consolidated sales be 300+400+400 = 1100?

Comment: Yes! I stand corrected. Thanks for that :) I am really stuck and lost on that problem.

Comment: Why are you taking a `SUM` of things? Could there be multiple discounts on a TenantCode on the same day?

Comment: because one tenantcode could have more than 1 terminalNo, and it is part of the column which I did not include, for shorter presentation. Each tenantcode should sum-up its over all sales combining all terminals. There is no problem actually in daily sales , cause I was able to achieve the desired output, my qquestion is with the CONSOLIDATED WHEN IT IS NOT DAILY, BUT GIVEN A RANGE OF DATE let's say per week or month

Comment: to answer, yes there could be thru two or more terminal no column all having the same tenantcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query for updating the GrossSales column in **Daily**  table.

```
UPDATE A
SET GrossSales = A.Cash + A.Charge + A.Gift + CASE WHEN A.TenantCode IS NOT NULL THEN A.Other ELSE 0
FROM Daily A LEFT JOIN Discount B on A.Date = B.Date and A.TenantCode = B.TenantCode
```

**EDIT:**

If GrossSales is not really a column, you can make use of temp table.

```
select *, 0 GrossSales
INTO #Daily
FROM Daily

UPDATE A
SET GrossSales = A.Cash + A.Charge + A.Gift + CASE WHEN A.TenantCode IS NOT NULL THEN A.Other ELSE 0
FROM #Daily A LEFT JOIN Discount B on A.Date = B.Date and A.TenantCode = B.TenantCode

UPDATE A
SET A.GrossSales = B.GrossSales
FROM Consolidated A JOIN (SELECT TenantCode, SUM(GrossSales) FROM #Daily GROUP BY TenantCode) B 
ON A.TenantCode = B.TenantCode
```

Comment: I forgot to put  emphasis that Gross Sales IS NOT A predefined column in daily table. It is only being formulated using a function , so that is not possible and one of the reasons why it is hard to achieve my desired output.

Comment: I will try your solution, THANKS A LOT! Just few quiestions  is it ideal to use a temp table t achieve my desired output? i mean performance wise.  Aren't there any solution to use without using a temp table but by plain query, subquery and the like?

Comment: Temp tables are generally better performant than subquery. It also provides reusability which subquery doesn't. Other option is to use a table variable too.

Comment: That's nice, could it also be read in crystal report thru sql command?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but there is no consolidated table. It is also customized, should i also create a temp table for it? based from what column?

Comment: I would suggest you to put the logic in an Stored Proc or to do the processing in database side. It would be much better performance wise to have your dataset of crystal report just doing a SELECT out of the final table.

Comment: I have not had much experience with crystal report, so can't comment much. SELECT out of temp tables wont worj for sure. Is it possible to invoke stored procs in crystal reports? If so you could have the entire logic wrapped in that and finally doing a SELECT out of the temp table. You could dump the entire logic in dataset but that would yield poor performance. Or third option would be to have the entire logic in one big SELECT statement which would look ugly and slow.

Comment: Thanks, that is also one of the reasons why i like it to be running in one select query or have subquery in it, for it to be catered in crystal reporting. I, too had this doubt if tempt table could run in crystal. On the other hand, the major disadvantage of the subquery is it executes slower..

Comment: Tried your solution but it did not go right, as the result i expected, but based on your concept, I was able to edit my previous  answer to achieve the desired result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: VOTED FOR IT AS AN ANSWER based on the concept presented, will that be violating any rule here?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.tenantcode,  convert(varchar(10), a.date, 101) as Date,  
SUM(a.other)  as Other, 
SUM(a.CASH) as Cash,
SUM(a.CHARGE) AS Charge,
SUM(a.GIFT) AS Gift,

case 

when a.date IN (select b.date from discount b  where b.date between '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014' and b.tenantcode = 'CMMISL13')
THEN (SUM(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift))

ELSE ((SUM(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift) + SUM(a.other)) - SUM(a.surcharge))
END as GrossSales

into #NewDailyTemp //Include it to create a temp table

from  TENANT b inner join LOCATION c on b.location=c.location inner join DAILY a on a.tenantcode=b.tenantcode

where b.tenantcode = 'CMMISL13'  AND 
    a.date  BETWEEN  '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014'


GROUP BY a.tenantcode , a.date
```

---

then

```
SELECT tenantcode, SUM(GrossSales) 
    from #NewDailyTemp
    where tenantcode = 'CMMISL13'  AND 
    date  BETWEEN  '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014'
    group by tenantcode
```

DESIRED OUTPUT WAS ACHIEVED. Integrating it to ASP.NET programming and crystal report is another subject though

Comment: But still it is not one line sql query and that's somehow frustrating THOUGH OUTPUT-WISE, it is okay, maybe it is really not possible to do a one line query for my desired output. ??

Comment: This answer is correct per TENANT, but to achieve the ALL TENANT , it is not giving the right answer, I will update my question for clarity.